# How to use Binary Encoding of Categorical Columns to predict labels in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, categorical-data

I have 2 files `test.csv` and `train.csv`. The attribute values are categorical and I am trying to convert them into numerical values.

I am doing the following:

```
import category_encoders as ce
encoder = ce.BinaryEncoder(cols = 'column_name' , return_df = True)
x_train_data = encoder.fit_transform(x_train_data)
```

This resulted in a new table with a total of 13 columns.
After that, I am training my `DecisionTreeClassifier` on `x_train_data` and `y_train_data`

Finally, I want to predict the `Labels` in `test.csv`.
If I repeat the BinaryEncoding procedure again on the test.csv, this time it is resulting in `< 13 features` which I think is due to a lesser number of rows.
Due to the difference in total columns, the decision tree classifier won't work.

So, is there a way to predict? And if not then what is the point of Binary Encoder? Since I assume we train a model so that we can predict on an unknown dataset.

Comment: As the answer below points out, we *never* `fit` (or `fit_transform`) the *test* (and generally unseen) data - we just `transform` them.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. And I don't know how I missed this. Still a newbie.

Comment: Gotcha! Accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do the `transform()` on the test data (and do not fit the encoder again). The values that don't occur in "training" datasets would be encoded as 0 in all of the categories (as long as you won't change the `handle_unknown` parameter). For example:

```py
import category_encoders as ce

train = pd.DataFrame({"var1": ["A", "B", "A", "B", "C"], "var2":["A", "A", "A", "A", "B"]})

encoder = ce.BinaryEncoder(cols = ['var1', 'var2'] , return_df = True)
x_train_data = encoder.fit_transform(train)

#   var1_0  var1_1  var2_0  var2_1
#0  0       1       0       1
#1  1       0       0       1
#2  0       1       0       1
#3  1       0       0       1
#4  1       1       1       0

test = pd.DataFrame({"var1": ["C", "D", "B"], "var2":["A", "C", "F"]})
x_test_data = encoder.transform(test)

#   var1_0  var1_1  var2_0  var2_1
#0  1       1       0       1
#1  0       0       0       0
#2  1       0       0       0
```

`'D'` doesn't occur in `var1` in training data, so it was encoded as `0  0`. `'C'` and `'F'`don't occur in `var2` in training data, so they were both encoded as `0  0`.